# How do I add a clickable button in qt for a GUI

Tags: qt, button, signals-slots

I want to make a button draw a graphic. I accomplished the drawing of the graphic, but I need it to wait until the "draw button" is clicked to draw the graphic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a [QPushButton](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qpushbutton.html#details) then it will emit a `clicked()` "signal" when the user clicks it.  You will need to connect that "signal" to a "slot".

The signal and slot mechanism is fundamental to how Qt works...so you should definitely read up on it:

http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/signalsandslots.html

This tutorial might help you some:

http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_QPushButton_in_Qt